# How adequate is this priming job?

Tags: painting

I'm priming the walls to rest some paint colors. How solidly white does the primer have to look. Is this ok or should I not be able to see underneath with the primer layer?[image: priming wall]

Comment: Is there a drastic difference between the colours? Are you going from oil pain to acrylic? As Jimmy Fix-it mentioned in his answer, you might not have to prime at all.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to use primer on a previously painted surface** that is properly prepared, unless there is some problem with the surface that makes you concerned about inadequate adhesion.

Buy good quality paint with high white pigment (titanium dioxide) content and you will be (or would have been) fine. Apply 2 coats of *paint* if it doesn't cover for some reason (like poor technique or wrong applicator). *What is this obsession with primer, do people just like to spend more money??*

Comment: It depends on the base coat. if he's going from blue to red, or black to white, for example, he will most definitely have to prime.

Comment: @chris, I totally disagree. Primer is for surface preparation. There are specialty "hiding" primers with a lot of pigment but good quality paints have a lot of pigment too. Nothing is easy to cover with red (as it contains very little titanium dioxide which is the best "hiding" pigment); blue (or any dark color) paint would be easier to cover with red paint than white primer. Just use more coats of red paint, why buy two products?

Comment: We've run in to instances where more coats didn't matter and we had to re-coat with primer. Besides the potential of wasted resources by having to re-work jobs, primer is 1/2 the price of top-coat per liter. At the end of the day, what matters is the communication with the customer, or your own personal preferences if you're working your own property.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on quality of paint that will be the topcoat, and how color sensitive the audience is, but looks like it needs a second coat of primer regardless, and i'd second coat regardless.